# Adding helper methods to Laravel Eloquent models?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to add a helper method like this to my Eloquent model

```
public function fullName()
{
    return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
}
```

Where `first_name` and `last_name` are properties of the model. So I can simply use `$user->fullName()` in views to return the full name of the user.

How can I achieve this? At the moment I get `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` error from trying the above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use an [acccessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) method like this:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
{{ $user->full_name }}
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Didn't even see that part of the docs. Thanks very much!!

Comment: The link for "Accessors & Mutators" in the Laravel 5.1 docs is http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators